# Unable to do bower install

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install [angular-material-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) using bower. When I run `bower info` on it, I get `0.10.9` and `0.10.10` as versions. But when I try to install those specific versions, it gives `ENORESTARGET` error.

I thought it was a cache issue so I tried to use `--force` option too. I even tried to install without mentioning any specific version to get the same error. Am I missing something here?

Here's the `bower info` and `bower install` command output -

```
$ bower info angular-material-data-table
bower cached        https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table.git#0.10.10
bower validate      0.10.10 against https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table.git#*

{
  name: 'angular-material-data-table',
  version: '0.10.10',
  description: 'Material Design data table.',
  main: [
    'dist/md-data-table.js',
    'dist/md-data-table.css'
  ],
  repository: {
    type: 'git',
    url: 'git://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table.git'
  },
  authors: [
    'Daniel Nagy'
  ],
  homepage: 'http://danielnagy.me/md-data-table',
  license: 'MIT',
  keywords: [
    'material',
    'table',
    'md-data-table'
  ],
  ignore: [
    '**/.*',
    'app',
    'bower_components',
    'node_modules',
    'src',
    'Gruntfile.js'
  ],
  dependencies: {
    angular: '^1.4.0',
    'angular-material': '^1.0.0'
  }
}

Available versions:
  - 0.10.10
  - 0.10.9
  - 0.10.8
  - 0.10.7
  - 0.10.6
  - 0.10.5
  - 0.10.4
  - 0.10.3
  - 0.10.2
  - 0.10.1
  - 0.10.0
  - 0.9.15
  - 0.9.14
  - 0.9.13
  - 0.9.12
  - 0.9.11
  - 0.9.10
  - 0.9.9
  - 0.9.8
  - 0.9.7
  - 0.9.6
  - 0.9.5
  - 0.9.4
  - 0.9.3
  - 0.9.2
  - 0.9.1
  - 0.9.0
  - 0.8.14
  - 0.8.13
  - 0.8.12
  - 0.8.11
  - 0.8.10
  - 0.8.9
  - 0.8.8
  - 0.8.7
  - 0.8.6
  - 0.8.5
  - 0.8.4
  - 0.8.3
  - 0.8.2
  - 0.8.1
  - 0.8.0
  - 0.7.6

You can request info for a specific version with 'bower info angular-material-data-table#<version>'



$ bower install --save-exact angular-material-data-table#0.10.9
bower not-cached    https://github.com/russellmorley/angular-sig-pad.git#undefined
bower resolve       https://github.com/russellmorley/angular-sig-pad.git#undefined
bower cached        https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table.git#0.10.9
bower validate      0.10.9 against https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table.git#0.10.9
bower ENORESTARGET  Tag/branch undefined does not exist

Additional error details:
Available tags: v0.1.0
Available branches: master
$
```

Comment: Why are you using bower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error due to having a different dependency in my bower.json having branch set as undefined

```
"angular-sig-pad": "https://github.com/russellmorley/angular-sig-pad.git#undefined"
```

So it was not the problem of angular-material-data-table. I should better check my bower.json next time, before posting question here.